# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com" when I run an Android Facebook app after closing emulator

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am able to see facebook groups when I run app for the first time.
But when I close the emulator and run my application again, I am getting the following response.

```
{Response:  responseCode: unknown, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com": No address associated with hostname}, isFromCache:false}
```

I used the following code for fetching Facebook groups:

```
    Request request = new Request(session, "/me/groups", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                     //code for displaying groups in list view as response contains groups information

            });
    request.executeAsync();
```

Am I missing any session handling use cases?

Comment: Make sure you have always connected to stable internet

Comment: @DavidJhons Thanks for the response. I am connected to stable internet. When i run again after "rebuild project" I can get groups. I believe this is something to do session handling.

Comment: Please explain how you can be running an android app after you closed the emulator.